# Storybook on Vite not starting: storybook bash script trying to exec a Node.js script

Tags: node.js, bash, vite, storybook

**Important: See "Update" below.**

I'm running Storybook `7.5.3` for Vue.js on Vite `4.5.0` with Node.js `v21.1.0`. When I try `npm run storybook`, I get the following error:

```bash
[29648:1206/145822.304:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(303)] 
Most NODE_OPTIONs are not supported in packaged apps. See documentation for more details.
```

It must be related to the `storybook` binary in `./node_modules/.bin/`.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

exec "$basedir/../spdx-correct/index.js"   "$@"
```

VSCode automatically opens the `.../spdx-correct/index.js` referenced in the above script after the error appears.

I receive this error even when my `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable is omitted or empty.

## Update

After starting my machine today, I'm no longer getting the "Most NODE_OPTIONs..." error. However, the `spdx-correct/index.js` file is still being opened in VSCode. It makes not sense why the script is trying to `exec` a `.js` file. I'm assuming this is the main issue. **Why is `storybook` trying to `exec` a Node.js script that seemingly has no relevance to a storybook server process?**

## System info

- Windows 11
- Node.js `v21.1.0`
- NPM `v10.2.0`
- Storybook `v7.5.3`
- Vite `v4.5.0`

**Note:** I'm getting the same results on Storybook `v7.6.0`.

## `.storybook/main.js`

```js
export default {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-interactions'],
  staticDirs: ['../public'],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/vue3-vite",
    options: {}
  },
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-vite', //  The builder enabled here.
    disableTelemetry: true,
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: true
  }
};
```

## `package.json`

```
{
  /* ... */
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "serve": "npm run dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "compile": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "storybook": "storybook dev"
  },
  "main": "dist/library.min.js",
  "module": "dist/library.min.mjs",
  "files": [
    "dist/*"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0",
    "autosize": "^5.0.2",
    "case": "^1.6.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "floating-vue": "^2.0.0-beta.20",
    "vue-draggable-plus": "^0.2.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^23.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.2.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/builder-vite": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/cli": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.1.0",
    "@storybook/vue3": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/vue3-vite": "^7.5.3",
    "@testing-library/vue": "^7.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.1",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "deepmerge": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^3.5",
    "rollup-plugin-clear": "^2.0.7",
    "rollup-plugin-filesize": "^9.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-import-css": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-progress": "^1.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-version-injector": "^1.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^5.8.3",
    "rollup-plugin-vue": "^6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "storybook": "^7.0.18",
    "storybook-dark-mode": "^3.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.11",
    "vitest": "^0.34.6",
    "vue": "^3.3.8",
    "vue-loader": "^16.8.3",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "markdown-to-jsx": "7.2.1",
    "node-ipc@>9.2.1 <10": "9.2.1",
    "node-ipc@>10.1.0": "10.1.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.3.8"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to fix: Re-initialize Storybook

I solved this by re-initializing Storybook from scratch.

*Note: I am working with Storybook `v7.6.4`.*

1. Removed `./node_modules/` and `./package-lock.json`.

   ```bash
   rm -rf ./node_modules
   ```
2. Remove all Storybook-related dependencies and scripts from `package.json`.
3. Re-initialize Storybook:

   ```bash
   npx storybook@latest init
   ```
4. Install all NPM dependencies.

   ```bash
   npm install
   ```
5. Run Storybook.

   ```bash
   npm run storybook
   ```

## Explaining the fix

It seems that since I converted my *existing* Storybook installation from Webpack to Vite, some adverse changes were automatically applied to the `storybook`, `storybook.ps1`, and `storybook.cmd` scrpts in `node_modules/.bin/`. These scripts are responsible for starting the Storybook application.

Remember, these scripts were calling an obscure `index.js` script of an `spdx-correct` dependency, which is obviously unrelated to a Storybook application.

```
# ./node_modules/.bin/storybook
# ...
exec "$basedir/../spdx-correct/index.js"   "$@"
```

After re-initializing Storybook, the scripts are corrected, pointing to `../storybook/index.js`:

```
# ./node_modules/.bin/storybook
# ...
if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  exec "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../storybook/index.js" "$@"
else 
  exec node  "$basedir/../storybook/index.js" "$@"
fi
```